# What is the smallest $i$ such that ZFC proves $\mathfrak c\le \aleph_i$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, real-numbers

I think we have that $\aleph_{\mathfrak c}\ge\mathfrak c$. But are there tighter upper bounds for $\mathfrak c$ in ZFC or no such bound is dependent on ZFC?

Comment: [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis#Independence_from_ZFC): "A result of Solovay, proved shortly after Cohen's result on the independence of the continuum hypothesis, shows that in any model of ZFC, if $\kappa$ is a cardinal of uncountable cofinality, then there is a forcing extension in which $2^{\aleph _{0}}=\kappa$." This seems to exclude an explicitly described (in a reasonable way) ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\aleph_\alpha$ is provably larger than $\mathfrak c$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by $i$.

Indeed, by the work of Cohen, extended by Solovay and ultimately Easton, we know that there is very little to be said in $\sf ZFC$ on the continuum function. In particular, given a model of set theory $V$, for every ordinal $\alpha$, there is an extension of $V$ with the same ordinals and same $\aleph$s, in which  $\frak c\geq\aleph_\alpha$. Therefore in that sense, there is no provable bound on the continuum.

But at the same time, what you write is true. $\frak c\leq\aleph_{\frak c}$. Taking the least cardinal that has $\frak c$ cardinals below it, then by definition this cardinal is at least $\frak c$. Even more is possible, it is possible that $\frak c=\aleph_{\frak c}$.

Now why is that not a "provable bound"? Because the value of $\frak c$ is not absolute and itself not computable. The cardinal $\frak c$ is not a fixed ordinal, so putting it in the index of an $\aleph$ is awkward, to the sense that this will be a different cardinal in different models of set theory, even if they have the same cardinals; whereas $\aleph_1$ is always the same in models which agree about cardinals.

So no, there is no provable bound; and to the extent possible, $\aleph_{\frak c}$ is the best we can do, since we can get equality, so certainly nothing smaller is provably smaller.

If you allow to use $\beth$ numbers, then $\beth_1$ is by definition $\frak c$, but of course, the function mapping each $\beth$ to its $\aleph$ value is not determined by the axioms of $\sf ZFC$. So we're back to where we started.

Comment: Is the result in your second paragraph independent of how large $V$ is? If $V$ has standard integers but $\aleph_\alpha\in V$ is larger than the metalevel's $\mathfrak{c}$, then it would seem to produce a contradiction if the model could be extended with enough new reals. I could believe it if $V$ is countable, though.

Comment: @Henning: Yes, of course. (This is the downside of forcing, formally speaking it only works "well" over countable transitive models, but in practice, we might as well assume that whenever we have a model of any "reasonable extension of ZFC" (i.e. not ZFC+"ZFC is inconsistent" or something), then the model we care about is a countable transitive model.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: do you have a reference for the independence of $\aleph_{\mathfrak c} = \mathfrak c$?

Comment: @PseudoNeo: Use the theorem of Cohen-Solovay, starting from CH, for any cardinal with uncountable cofinality there is a forcing extension where the continuum is that cardinal. Now take any $\aleph$ fixed point of uncountable cofinality.